# Token-based access to github inside remote machine shared with other people

Tags: git, github, passwords, token

In my lab, students share the same workstation running ubuntu. Each student has own user, but anybody can see my home directory. Because of this reason, I didn't put my private ssh key there, and I always used to use password to push/fetch from the github repo.

Since today, Github start to not allow us to use password to push/fetch, and it seems to me that there are only two ways: ssh-based or token-based.

As mentioned earlier, I can't put my private ssh-key on the remote machine, so I have to use token. However, tokens are too long to remember and also I cannot save the token on the remote machine for the security reason (I don't want other lab member can access to my github private repo ofcourse). This means whenever I fetch/push, I have to always copy-and-past the token.

This process is so bothersome. Is there any better practice to circumvent this?

Comment: Consider encrypting your ssh key on the ubuntu workstation, or using ssh-agent if you can use your own computer to log in to the lab ubuntu workstation, or bypassing the lab workstation entirely. All of these methods will allow you to use ssh: you will just have to enter the decryption key to decrypt the access to the private key.

Comment: Did you try generating ssh key with a password? Then even if anyone uses your ssh key they would be required to enter the password. I'm unaware if there are any other security concerns regarding this though.

Comment: @GaneshPendyala Thanks, I didn't  know that. That's a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, tokens are too long to remember and also I cannot save the token on the remote machine for the security reason

You can save it (encrypted) on the remote machine: Use [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/) (which does [support Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/135#issuecomment-892856585), as a [package](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/README.md#linux)), provided you are adding a [credential store](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md).

> but anybody can see my home directory

Nothing prevents you to:

- chmod 700 your home
- move the common resources outside your home, for others to access to.